# Need help to understand vector differentiation?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a matrix.

$\bar{X}$ and $\bar{b}$ are vectors.

$\bar{X}$ contains coefficients such as $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$

The origianl matrix equation is as follows:

$E = \bar{X}^TA^TA\bar{X}-\bar{X}A^T\bar{b}-\bar{b}^TA\bar{X}+\bar{b}^T\bar{b}$

I need to differentiate the above matrix equation $E$ on $a$ in vector $\bar{X}$

$\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial \bar{a}} = \dfrac{\partial \bar{X}}{\partial \bar{a}}(A^TA)\bar{X} + \left(\bar{X}^T(A^TA)\dfrac{\partial \bar{X}}{\partial \bar{a}}\right)^T\dots$

I don't understand the first transpose part, $\left(\bar{X}^T(A^TA)\dfrac{\partial \bar{X}}{\partial \bar{a}}\right)^T$

Why do I need to transpose that part? And when I differentiate, do I differentiate first and then transpose?

Comment: Maybe look here at identities table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I think it should be $E = \bar{X}^TA^TA\bar{X} - \dots$ otherwise it doesn't make sense. Also vectors are usually not in capital letter, i.e. $\bar{x}$. And finally what is $\bar{a}$?

Comment: Yeah, I just check and you are right.